# How to fix 415 Unsupported Media Type for Rest API between Angular 7 and Java

Tags: java, rest, api, angular7

This is the first time i developed Java Rest API. I m trying to integrate REST API in Angular 7 but i m getting an error.

**415 Unsupported Media Type**

```
package org.jasyatra.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.jasyatra.model.AdminLogin;
import org.jasyatra.model.LoginAuthToken;
import org.jasyatra.service.AdminLoginService;
import org.jasyatra.service.LoginAuthTokenService;

@RestController
public class AdminLoginController {

    @Autowired
    AdminLoginService adminLoginService;

    @Autowired
    LoginAuthTokenService loginAuthTokenService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Map login(@RequestBody AdminLogin parameters) {
        List<AdminLogin> loginResponse = adminLoginService.login(parameters);
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        if (loginResponse.size() > 0) {
            response.put("result", "true");
            response.put("id", Integer.toString(loginResponse.get(0).getId()));
            response.put("username", loginResponse.get(0).getUsername());
            response.put("role", loginResponse.get(0).getUserRole());
            List<LoginAuthToken> responseToken = loginAuthTokenService.getLatestToken(loginResponse.get(0).getId(), loginResponse.get(0).getUserRole());
            response.put("token", responseToken.get(0).getToken());
        } else {
            response.put("result", "false");
            response.put("message", "Invalid username or password!");
        }
        return response;
    }
}

adminLogin(params) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.api_url+'/admin/login', params, options).pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
}
```

If i don't send content-type in headers, i m getting this error:

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
```

If i send content-type in headers, i m getting this error:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
```

I have tried these kind of combinations but looks like none of them is working for me.

Can you please guide me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Your method accepts `application/json` but you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @BackSlash i m sending accept: application/json also as you can see in the code and i also mentioned that if i don't send content-type, i get Request Method: OPTIONS Status Code: 403 Forbidden error

Comment: Sending the `accept` header from client just tells the server that your client is able to understand `application/json`. `Content-Type` tells the server what kind of data you are sending, `Accept` server-side means that the server can understand that language. So, if `Accept` from server and `Content-Type` from client don't match, you'll get a 415. It may also happen that you get a 415 from a deserialization error (i.e. body cannot be parsed to `AdminLogin`), but it should generally fire a 400 instead.

Comment: @BackSlash, i have tried this also

headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

in this case, i m getting 403 forbidden error and requests header goes like this

Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/pages/auth/login

and i get response like this

Invalid CORS request

Comment: Then you should investigate server-side why this is happening, likely you'll have logs somewhere.

Comment: @BackSlash If i add this code in java api @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")

it works but then i see that if i call the api, first it comes up as 

Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK

and then automatically another request gets fired and in that i get success response

Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK

Can you tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` as `content-type`. You will need to specify that in the REST API. You should include `consumes` parameter in your `@RequestMapping`. Something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
```

<s>You will also need to remove the `@RequestBody` annotation on the method parameter</s>

```
// removed @RequestBody annotation
public Map login(AdminLogin parameters) {
    // .... body
}
```

You will need to use `RequestParam` annotation and modify your method like so

```
// using map to get all the keys & their values.
public Map login(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map){

}

// get all the form parameter in separate method parameter like so
// (key name are dummies here, use appropriate names when using)
public Map login(@RequestParam("key1") String key1, @RequestParam("key2") String key2){

}
```

I also think `headers` with `Accept` parameter section is unnecessary here.

Image showing the api called using Postman client (ignore the url here... just testing)
[image]

Image showing the value got in the map. Notice the data sent in the API call and data received in the map object.
[image]

Comment: If i remove the @RequestBody annotation, it started working but then i can't take out values from parameters. It's giving NullPointerExpection

Comment: Can you suggest a solution please?

Comment: I have updated the code. Submitted parameters can be caught either in a map or separated method parameters. I could not get the values in a custom class. Will give that a through try later.

Comment: Thanks but @RequestParam is not able to get POST method parameters. It is giving null if i do like this map.get('username')

Comment: @Ravinder, If this answer helps and works for you, please mark it as answer.